# Duplicate checking two very big tables

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I'm currently trying to check for duplicates across two tables, but these tables are huge I have two tables, one with about 60 million numbers and one with about 16 million numbers.

The server is a 16 Core Xeon, 32GB DDR3 RAM 14900, 2x 15K SAS. 
I tried to run this command `SELECT number FROM numbers,newData WHERE newData.number = numbers.number` so that I can find out how many duplicates we have, but I left it for 24 hours with no such luck.

I've now written a php script that loops through 20 at a time and write to the newData table yes if it exists, but this is taking 6 seconds per number.

How can I speed this up? I have done all the optimizations possible for mysql including the inno_db_buffer_pool.

Comment: left join 2nd tabel? use myisam instead of innodb? ....

Comment: comparing 60 million and 16 million shouldn't take 24 hours. Do you have indexes on the tables?

Comment: when 2 records are the same? when key is the same or you have more complex comparison ?

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems ok, but you should be sure that your number columns are indexed in both tables.

If they are not create an index over each of them, which could take a while and take some disk. But if this is something you want to run multiple times it will be worth it.

Comment: Well im debating in upping the RAM to 128GB and using the inno_db_buffer_pool really high to cache the tables, would it be worth it?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT number 
  FROM numbers
WHERE exists (
     select 1 
       From newData 
      where numbers.number = newData.number
)
```

OR

```
SELECT numbers.number 
  FROM numbers 
  JOIN newData 
  ON numbers.number = newData.number
```

If you could as well post the explain from both queries and from your query would be good.